# onCreate and onResume were called when app direct user to an activity

Tags: android, oncreate, onresume

I have an activity that lets the user to insert data from a custom dialog and a listview that display the data. After inputting the data in the dialog, the onResume is supposed to update the listview. The issue is that when the app directs the user to the activity, it calls both the onCreate and onResume, and it does not call the onResume after the user insert data from the dialog. What went wrong and how to solve it?

SubjectListActivity.java

```
public class SubjectListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        private static final String TAG = "SubjectListActivity";
        private Animation rotateOpen;
        private Animation rotateClose;
        private Animation fromBottom;
        private Animation toBottom;
        private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        private NavigationView navigationView;
        private Toolbar toolbar;
        private boolean clicked = false;
        private ListView lv_subjectList;
        private FloatingActionButton btn_subjectMenu, btn_subjectDelete, btn_subjectAdd;
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
        ArrayList<SubjectListModel> arrayList;
        SubjectListAdapter subjectListAdapter;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_subject_list);
            intViews();
            loadAnimation();
            databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
            arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            loadListView();
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    
            navigationView.bringToFront();
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();
    
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
    
            btn_subjectAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    openDialog();
                }
            });
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: ");
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            Log.i(TAG, "onResume: ");
            loadListView();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_subjectList);
        }
    
        public void loadListView () {
            arrayList = databaseHelper.getAllSubjectListData();
            subjectListAdapter = new SubjectListAdapter(this, arrayList);
            lv_subjectList.setAdapter(subjectListAdapter);
        }
    
        private void intViews() {
            toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            btn_subjectAdd = findViewById(R.id.btn_subjectAdd);
            btn_subjectMenu = findViewById(R.id.btn_subjectMenu);
            btn_subjectDelete = findViewById(R.id.btn_subjectDelete);
            lv_subjectList = findViewById(R.id.lv_SubjectList);
        }
    
        public void openDialog () {
            SubjectListDialog subjectListDialog = new SubjectListDialog();
            subjectListDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "subject list dialog");
        }
    
        
    }
```

SubjectListDialog.java

```
    public class SubjectListDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
        private EditText et_subjectCode, et_subjectName, et_creditHour;
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
        private ListView lv_SubjectList;
        SubjectListAdapter subjectListAdapter;
        SubjectListActivity subjectListActivity;
        ArrayList<SubjectListModel> arrayList;
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_subjectlist_dialog, null);
    
            builder.setView(view)
                    .setTitle("Add Subject")
                    .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
    
                        }
                    })
                    .setPositiveButton("confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            insert();
                            SubjectListDialog.this.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            et_subjectCode = view.findViewById(R.id.et_subjectCode);
            et_subjectName = view.findViewById(R.id.et_subjectName);
            et_creditHour = view.findViewById(R.id.et_creditHour);
            return builder.create();
        }
    
        public void insert() {
            boolean result = databaseHelper.insertSubjectList(et_subjectCode.getText().toString(), et_subjectName.getText().toString(),Integer.parseInt(et_creditHour.getText().toString()));
            if (result) {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Data has been added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Please insert all the fields correctly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you are done taking input you should dismiss the dialog. In your case after calling `insert()` call `SubjectListDialog.this.dismiss()`

**Update** - The dialog fragment does not pauses the activity it is just like a fragment is inflated inside the view bounds of the activity itself. This can be further confirmed with the fact that the it is added to screen using the activity's own fragment manager as done in your code `subjectListDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "subject list dialog");`

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it does not work

Comment: @Nomel so this means your activity is not pausing when you show the dialog fragment. You can pass a listener from Activity to fragment which can then be used called when positive or negative button is pressed and take action accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound incompetent, I'm new to android development. I only understand what you said up until you said "You can pass a listener from Activity to fragment ...".

Can you explain it with me with an example?

Comment: @Nomel you need to define an interface that has 2 methods one for positive case one for negative case. Then you can implement the same in your activity. Pass Activityname.this to your SubjectListDialog() constructor. Now when you receive callback in setNegativeButton listener then call the negative method of the object passed in constructor and when you receive positive then call the positive function of the object. Basically through this interface your fragment can talk to your activity.